# why the difference between two pointers pointing to different elements of an array is the no of elements between these two pointers?

Tags: c++11

```
int main()
{
    int arr[]={2,3,5,6,8};
    int *ptr;

    ptr=&arr[3];
    cout<<ptr-arr;
}
```

Q.why the answer is 3 after compiling the  code i.e. as it should be 3*sizeof(int) which in this case should be 3*4=12?

Answer (score 1):

When you subtract pointers you get the distance between them, not the allocated size. The same goes for iterators in STL.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Additive_operators

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that it is much easier to write correct code.

When the pointer difference between consecutive elements of an array is 1, then you can use `++p` to walk through the array (assuming `p` is a pointer to an element). For example:

```
int a[10];

for (auto p = a, e = a + 10; p != e; ++p)
    *p = 42;
```

Notice how the code does not have to deal with the size of the elements. If the array type changes from `int` to `double`, the code does not have to change and is still correct.